# Jasper PDF download local is not the same as PDF production

Tags: grails, jasper-reports

I built my system in grails and when I download my Pdf in my development(local), my report goes really nice. But when I put on production(another machine ubuntu) and download on it, the report goes bad. Keep cutting words, some `$P{...}` goes a little up. Why does it happen?

Look at this: [image]

- The dates "Iníci" should be "Início" and Términ should be "Término".
- The "Selo (Bentonita +" doesn't end with ")", because is cutting the word.
- The dates "03/03/2015" and "05/03/2015" is little up

In my local, everything is aligned and the labels are showing everything.

Comment: It looks like your font changed. Do you use jasperreports-font to make sure fonts are the same?

Comment: no, I just use the attributes, like font, pdfFontName, font, fontName

Comment: That means that the fonts are platform dependent and it can be a source of your problem. You should try using jasperreports-font

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `jasperreports-font` dependency to your BuildConfig.groovy:

```
dependencies {
    runtime 'net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports-fonts:6.0.0'
}
```

and in your report use only DejaVu fonts.

That should make sure you see the same report in development and production.

Comment: This works on ireport 4.0.1? Ill try when I get omw to work.

Comment: Adjust the version of `jasperreports-fonts` and it should work (I use it with jasperreports 6.x). You do not need to import it to ireport, only to your grails project. In ireport set the fonts to DejaVu.